# Start selenium server on CentOS

Tags: macos, angularjs, selenium, centos, protractor

I have a VM with centOS, I try to run selenium server by following [the tutorial here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md). When trying to start the selenium server with `webdriver-manager start` I get:

> execvp(): No such file or directory seleniumProcess.pid: 22847
>
> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

So I tried the same tutorial with my host (OSX) and running `webdriver-manager start` works perfectly. `curl 192.168.0.10:4444` from my guest successfully returns the page.

I have two questions.

Why is that so?

Can I have my tests in my VM, the Selenium server on my host and successfully run my tests? I just started with protractor and wonder if I should go further or if it's a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are making use of Java to run your test, you can make use of this jar file to run your [Selenium Standalone server](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar)

Command to run on your terminal
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar`

This will require you to have Java installed on your VM

Also, if you are making use of WebDriver and running single instance at a time, you won't be required to run selenium standalone server explicitly, FirefoxDriver runs directly without explicit server requirement. But if you want to run multiple test on your VM say 5 browsers at once, you will be required to create a Grid using [Selenium Grid 2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), which will require you to run your server using below code

Start Grid Server
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub`

Connect Grid node to Grid server
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register`

On java side, you will require RemoteWebDriver to run over this grid server as below,

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

Hope this helps you